# How to copy paste a created text(annotation) by "typewriter" menu tool?

Tags: linux, kde, pdf, free-software, okular

If I write an annotation by "typewriter" tool, how can I just duplicate it, copy pasting? I can't believe it is not doable....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could make a stamp from a png that contains your text and then stamp it all over the place. Not ideal and I myself look for a better solution.

Quick Annotations - Configure Annotations - Add - Type: Stamp - load png in stamp symbol

Better to just click with the stamp and not draw the rectangle, otherwise it gets stretched.

**Another, better option**: just use xournal++, much better at this and you can copy/paste created text-elements!